# Using plural noun + is and are

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Can we use "is" and "are" like this:

> EVs *is* a recent trend and *are* more common in our area than in my
> grandparents'.

Or, when to treat plural as a singular subject?

> These are our new computers, which *is* the only technology we use.

vs.

> These are our new computers, which *are* the only technology we use.

Comment: "Buying EVs" *is* a recent trend, but "EVs" *are* a recent trend.

Comment: Hello LShi and welcome to ELL. On this site, questions about finding mistakes and improving sentences are off-topic. If you have a question about a specific aspect of English, please ask a question about that. Why do you think "are" is correct in that sentence? Do you know the difference between "is" and "are"? Are you confused about whether to treat EVs as a singular or plural subject? Is this your own sentence or did you find it somewhere?

Comment: Hi gotube, thank you for your comment. I edited the question. Could you please take a look?